# Pertinent to the capital city

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective in English that means "pertinent to the capital city"? Example from Russian: The name of a certain [vodka brand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolichnaya) means "related to or coming from the capital city". I know at least one restaurant having the same name and there used to be sweets called like that.

Sample sentence (X is the word I'm looking for):

> The restaurant offered a variety of X dishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**capital**

> designating, of, or relating to a capital city.

(*Oxford English Dictionary*)

Also, there is the NHL team  Washington Capitals. Everyone knows what *capitals* refers to; it is just a plural of capital, referring to our nation's capital.

Comment: By that logic, wouldn't the Washington Capitals refer to [Olympia, the capital of Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympia,_Washington)?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest **metropolitan** (as in London's Metropolitan Police).